# "Never say never"

Tags: idioms

Since there is apparently no literal translation for "never", how would you translate this idiom ?

What periphrasis would you use to express the same meaning ?

Comment: Or you could take the katakana route and use [ネヴァー・セイ・ネヴァー](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/ジャスティン・ビーバー_ネヴァー・セイ・ネヴァー).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about something like 「絶対なんて絶対にない」? It has the same self-contradictory nature as the English original, and [seems to have some use as well](http://www.google.com/search?cx=c&ix=c2&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=%22%E7%B5%B6%E5%AF%BE%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A6%E7%B5%B6%E5%AF%BE%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%22). The meaning is slightly different, however. You could also go with something like 「ありえないなんてありえない」 or something...

Comment: If I may, you should use quotes in your google requests to actually match a strict pattern, 15,900 matches is still high and makes your point anyways. Well done!

Comment: quotes added :)

Comment: @Aki - This is completely off-topic, but what do you mean here by "periphrasis"?

Comment: @rdb Seems to me like [the ordinary meaning is fine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periphrasis).

Comment: Do you mean to say the OP wanted a phrase free of inflected words?

Comment: This is the definition I had in mind: "use of a longer phrasing in place of a possible shorter form of expression". Which may not be 100 % correct. Check out Wikipedia's article on [Circumlocution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumlocution).